# В чем разница между @Column(length = 1000) и @Column(columnDefinition = "text")

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

Я использую hibernate и postgres
В чем разница будет между

```
@Column(length = 1000)
private String string;
```

и

```
@Column(columnDefinition = "text")
private String string;
```

В первом случае явно указана длина строки, которая может храниться в бд. А во стором случае какое дефолтное значение длины строки, которое может хранится в бд?
Будет ли изменена JPA модель если использовать вместо первого случая второй или наоборот?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Тип поля таблицы в первом случае будет `varchar(1000)`, а во втором `text`. Тип `text` не ограничен в длине. В полях этого типа можно и гигабайт текста сохранить.